# Yii2 REST API doesn't return expected results

Tags: php, json, rest, yii, yii2

I'm trying to create a simple REST API with authentication. But, something is wrong.

I'm using the advanced template with Yii Framework 2. I never had programed for yii before, so I'm learning.

My code:

~/api
    -->config
      --> main.php

```
<?php

$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-api',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),    
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'modules' => [
        'v1' => [
            'basePath' => '@app/modules/v1',
            'class' => 'api\modules\v1\Module'
        ]
    ],
    'components' => [        
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'request' => [
            'class' => '\yii\web\Request',
            'enableCookieValidation' => false,
            'parsers' => [
                'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
            ],
        ],        
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
                    'controller' => 'v1/teste',
                    'extraPatterns' => [
                            'GET testando' => 'testando',
                        ],
                ],
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                    'controller' => 'v1/user',
                    'extraPatterns' => [
                            'GET login' => 'login',
                        ],
                ],
                'OPTIONS v1/user/login' => 'v1/user/login',
                'POST v1/user/login' => 'v1/user/login',
            ],        
        ]
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

--> modules --> v1 --> controllers --> TesteController.php

```
<?php

namespace api\modules\v1\controllers;

//Formato json
use yii\filters\ContentNegotiator;
use yii\web\Response;

//Banco de dados
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

//Segurança
use yii\filters\auth\CompositeAuth;
use yii\filters\auth\QueryParamAuth;

//Rest api
use yii\rest\ActiveController;

/**
 * Country Controller API
 *
 * @author Budi Irawan <deerawan@gmail.com>
 */
class TesteController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'api\modules\v1\models\Teste';

    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => QueryParamAuth::className(),
        ];
        $behaviors['bootstrap'] = [
            'class' => ContentNegotiator::className(),
        'formats' => [
            'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
        ],
    ];  
        return $behaviors;  
    }

    public function actionTestando(){
    echo "testado";
    }
}
```

--> modules --> v1 --> controllers --> UserController.php

```
<?php
namespace api\modules\v1\controllers;

use common\models\LoginForm;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class UserController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'common\models\User';

    public function actionLogin()
    {
        $model = new LoginForm();

        if ($model->load(\Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams(), '') && $model->login()) {
            echo \Yii::$app->user->identity->getAuthKey();
        } else {
            return $model;
        }
    }

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        if (\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            throw new \HttpHeaderException();
        }
        return \Yii::$app->user->getId();
    }
}
```

--> modules --> v1 --> models --> Teste.php

```
<?php

namespace api\modules\v1\models;

use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;

use \yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Teste extends ActiveRecord 
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%teste}}';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            TimestampBehavior::className(),
        ];
    }
}
```

--> modules --> v1 --> models --> User.php

```
<?php

namespace api\modules\v1\models;

use common\models\User as CommonUser;

class User extends CommonUser
{

}
```

--> modules --> v1 --> Module.php

```
<?php
namespace api\modules\v1;

class Module extends \yii\base\Module
{
    public $controllerNamespace = 'api\modules\v1\controllers';

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();        
    }
}
```

Then when I'm testing the REST API with:

```
curl -D- -u admin:123mudar! -H "Content-Type:application/json" 'http://www.domain.com/v1/testa/api/web/v1/testes'
```

I've got:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Mon, 18 Aug 2014 22:44:10 GMT
Server: Apache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{"type":"yii\\web\\UnauthorizedHttpException","name":"Unauthorized","message":"You are requesting with an invalid access token.","code":0,"status":401}
```

Even when I'm using the restClient plugin. What is missing?

Database table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `teste` (
  `codigo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`codigo`),
  KEY `nome` (`nome`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `teste` (`codigo`, `nome`) VALUES
(1, 'valor 1'),
(2, 'valor 2');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `auth_key` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `password_hash` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password_reset_token` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `role` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '10',
  `status` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '10',
  `created_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;


INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `username`, `auth_key`, `password_hash`, `password_reset_token`, `email`, `role`, `status`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, 'admin', '79UF7P3XNV9t075lv1kA8G3mYVaysaIw', '$2y$13$A8x5bNgFSwyN6RTFtgZ2h.oGu87gWqiRrci/jZYzT.KwF6o6sLTzC', NULL, 'admin@admin.com', 10, 10, 1408061655, 1408061655);
```

Comment: It looks like you've set an authenticator in your config. Can you add debug statements to that class temporarily to see what is going wrong? I assume, given the API output, that it's an auth problem you're looking at?

Comment: How can I do that? I'm a beginner and don't have idea.. tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii2 RESTful API use an `access-token` to authenticate instead of `username:password` , if you user table doesn't have an `access_token` column， create one and update your user;

Yii2 basic Template's User Model has `access_token`, like below:

`private static $users = [
        '100' => [
            'id' => '100',
            'username' => 'admin',
            'password' => 'admin',
            'authKey' => 'test100key',
            'accessToken' => '100-token',
        ],
        '101' => [
            'id' => '101',
            'username' => 'demo',
            'password' => 'demo',
            'authKey' => 'test101key',
            'accessToken' => '101-token',
        ],
    ];`

Then, when you request, use this `accessToken` as the `username` and left `password` empty, have a try.

Another way, your can use `use yii\filters\auth\QueryParamAuth;` and just use `curl http://192.168.4.126/news/126?access-token=100-token` to test, both OK.

more detail, you can refer to my article:

http://www.cnblogs.com/ganiks/p/yii2-restful-api-dev.html

At the End, if you really want to use `username:password`， you can re-construct yii2-rest, refer to :

http://www.cnblogs.com/ganiks/p/yii2-restful-api-mechanism.html

Comment: lol... thank you.. definitely, I'll use other framework to acquire it... its a lot unsecured this rest, using only a access-token..  and re-construct the yii2 rest, certainly will be a pain.. even more, because yii2 is still a beta release..  :p.. I tought to use magento soap... thank you again

Comment: @DMiller, perhaps using only an access token (without expiring it) is not secure enough, but I want to point out that using only username:password is not securer either. It is suggested to read articles about common practices of RESTful authentication. In short, if someone steals your credential, your account will be exposed forever unless you update it. If someone steals your access token, your account will be exposed until the expiry of the token. And using access token can reduce the need of sending username:password in every request, thus is practically securer.

Comment: I was looking for access-token based authentication and this solution also worked for me, thanks a ton.

Answer (score 5):

Answer from @Ganiks is a bit misleading. You don't have to re-construct anything, what you need to do is to override the controller behaviors and add a custom callback for credential checking. It is not necessary to have **access token** in your identity model, too.

### Quick solution:

```
$behaviors['authenticator'] = [
    'class' => HttpBasicAuth::className(),
    'auth' => function ($username, $password) {
        // Return Identity object or null
        return User::findOne([
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password
        ]);
    },
];
```

The official guideline introduces the concept of using **access token** in Yii2 RESTful APIs (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-authentication.html) and the proper way to set up. Despite this, the built-in authenticator `HttpBasicAuth` is actually using **username:password**.

In fact, access token in *HTTP Basic Auth* is actually encoded from username:password, see the definition at wiki (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Protocol).

Comment: Is there any better tutorial about how to authenticate user. I just can't figure it out

Comment: @FosAvance honestly I just read the source code and documentation and guess how they works. I have another answer from here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27353263/yii2-how-exactly-does-user-authentication-works/27354326#27354326 that asking how does the authentication work, see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I have my rest api asking for username and password. But, always get error 401.

To ask for username and password, I had to change:
--> modules --> v1 --> controllers --> TesteController.php

```
<?php
namespace api\modules\v1\controllers;
//Formato json
use yii\filters\ContentNegotiator;
use yii\web\Response;
//Banco de dados
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

//Segurança
use yii\filters\auth\CompositeAuth;
//use yii\filters\auth\QueryParamAuth; ####################### <<<<<<<<<---- QUERYPARAMS TO HTTPBASICAUTH
use yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth;

//Rest api
use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class TesteController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'api\modules\v1\models\Teste';

    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        /*$behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => QueryParamAuth::className(),
        ];*/
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => HttpBasicAuth::className(), //###### <<<<<-------- FROM QueryParamAuth::className(), to HttpBasicAuth::className()
        ];  
        $behaviors['bootstrap'] = [
            'class' => ContentNegotiator::className(),
        'formats' => [
            'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
        ],
    ];  
        return $behaviors;  

        /*return [
        'bootstrap' => [
        'class' => ContentNegotiator::className(),
        'formats' => [
            'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
        ],
        ],

            'authenticator' => [
        'class' => CompositeAuth::className(),
            ],
    ];*/
    }



    public function actionTestando(){
    echo "testado";
    }

}
```

The user is admin and password is 123mudar!
Even informing the correct user and password, I always receive Unauthorized access.

Thanks