# Yii2: How exactly does user authentication works?

Tags: php, yii2

I don't understand `Authentication` in `Yii2`. In `Yii 1` there was an identity class where we need to work with the `authentication()` method and call `CWebUser::login()` to achieve our goals.

What are the main processes of authentication in `Yii 2`? **And how does it work exactly?**

Can you please explain the following:

- All the steps required to complete authentication.
- Required database fields or schema.
- How to authenticate multiple user types.
- What may be a few other things I need to consider?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To answer your questions, it is needed to understand one thing - `Yii2` provides some *helper* classes / interfaces for developers to implement user authentication easily, but it is not always required to follow or use any of them. So my following answer is just explaining the *default* behavior of some classes.

And it is always a good starting point to look at the **Yii2 Advanced template** and the source code to understand the workflow of the framework, it is surprisingly easy to read, in my opinion.

### - how does it work exactly

`Yii2` framework provides a number of *core* components in its static context, you can always call them through `Yii::$app->`. One of the core components is `user`, it is actually an instance of `yii\web\User` and all the *default* magic are inside this class.

Not only `user`, you may also need to use other *core* components as well. I am not sure how deep you want to understand the way it works, if I don't give you a deep enough explanation, I strongly suggest you to read source code. You will have the source code on your hand once you did `composer install`, or go to their github to have a code tracing - https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/tree/master/framework

### - All the steps required to complete authentication.

Firstly, you should have a `User` class which implements `IdentityInterface` and extends `ActiveRecord`, please see the example in Advance template: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/common/models/User.php .

And in your configuration, set the `$identityClass` of `user` component to the above custom `User` class. This is the minimal setup for `User`.

Next, you must have a controller with a method mapped to a request url such as "/login". In this method, you should use your way to extract the `User` instance - `$u`. This is the location where your authentication should be.

Then you can call `Yii::$app->user->login($u)` to login; `Yii::$app->user->logout()` to logout.

After you login, you can get the current user instance anywhere through `Yii::$app->user->identity`.

### - Required database fields or schema.

It is up to you, depending on your need. The template just gives you an idea on how to design the `User` ActiveRecord class but not bounded by it - `username` and `passwordHash` are something very common but you can always have your own schema.

### - How to authenticate multiple user types.

I don't quite understand the problem. Hope others could help.

### - What may be a few other things I need to consider?

If you decide to use RESTful supported by the framework, remember to implement `findIdentityByAccessToken()` in your `User` class, see details in http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-authentication.html

I can think of one at this moment, may add other things later.